# Handle Swift-nio server-side TCP connection event and send context data to client

Tags: swift-nio

I'm working on a COPS (rfc 2748) protocol handler. I need to be able to send a message from the server to the client immediately after a TCP connection is established. I'm not finding any API that describes this capability.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a ChannelHandler into the pipeline of newly connected sockets using `channel.pipeline.addHandler(MyHandler())` in `childChannelInitializer` that just sends data using `context.writeAndFlush` when your ChannelHandler receives the `channelActive` event. SwiftNIO will send this right when the TCP connection is up.